# Странная работа в NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Написал программу на java в NetBeans

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package workwithstrings;

/**
 *
 * @author Asus
 */
import java.util.*;
public class WorkWithStrings {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    String s, substring;
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Введите строку: ");
    s=in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Введите подстроку: ");
    substring=in.nextLine();
    if (s.indexOf(substring)!=-1)
    {
        System.out.println("Подстрока "+substring+" присутствует в строке "+s);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Подстрока "+substring+" не присутствует в строке "+s);        
    };

    }
}
```

В результате при вводе латинсих символов программа работает нормально. А при вводе русских после ввода первой строки и нажатия Enter не появляется строки приглашения

```
Введите подстроку:
```

Приходится нажимать второй раз Enter и терятеся возможность ввода подстроки. Врезультате программа говорит, что подстрока найдена. Вот вывод программы

```
run:
Введите строку: 
ыипмаврперапроао

Введите подстроку: 
Подстрока  присутствует в строке ����������������
ПОСТРОЕНИЕ УСПЕШНО ЗАВЕРШЕНО (общее время: 13 секунд)
```

А при латинских символах выполняется нормально:

```
run:
Введите строку: 
dhgfhjh
Введите подстроку: 
a
Подстрока a не присутствует в строке dhgfhjh
ПОСТРОЕНИЕ УСПЕШНО ЗАВЕРШЕНО (общее время: 8 секунд)
```

Comment: Вопрос требует уточнений. Какая система? Какой вид терминала?
Ответ: "Сменить кодировку с UTF-8 на windows-1251 подойдет только пользователям Windows" , однако UTF-8 более распространенная и в ней без проблем могут отображаться русские буквы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте сменить
 1. Кодировку проекта.
 2. Кодировку консоли Java(ps. геморно, сложно, ничего не дает - не пробуйте:) )

Comment: Надо сменить кодировку с UTF-8 на windows-1251.